# replace div with rails using link_to

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I would like to replace a div content with a content of another html.erb page, now i know its possible with link_to, and it worked for me:

in the view:

```
link_to host, { :controller => "test_queues", :action => "show_host", :id => id}, {:target => "host_queues"} %>
<iframe name="host_queues", scrolling="yes" width="82%" height="700px", align="right", frameborder="0", rel="stylesheet"></iframe>
```

In the controller:

```
  def show_host

    queue = testQueue.find(params[:id])

    @test_queues = testQueue.where(:host => queue.host)

    respond_to do |format|

      format.html { render action: "show_host", :layout => nil}

      format.json { render json: @test_queue }

    end

  end
```

And there is a page called show_host.html.erb

Now, when i want to replace the div content, it doesnt work, it just redirects me to show_host.html.erb

So how can i replace the div using this method ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the `remote: true` option in your `link_to` method.

You may also need to add a

```
format.js { render layout: false }
```

to your controller method.

Comment: Nope, no errors  
<%= link_to host, { :controller =>"test_queues", :action => "show_host", :id => id, :remote=>true}, {:target=>"host_queues"}%>

Comment: yes, i did:


    respond_to do |format|

      format.html { render action: "show_host", :layout => nil}

      format.json { render json: @kashmir_queue }

      format.js { render layout: false }

    end